# Format time zone to Vi Locale use Moment in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

i am having a date problem when using Moment in React-Native.
Specifically, after I formatted the date to en locale, but now I want it to support the locale in my country is vi locale as well:

```
Moment('2022-09-02T02:00:00+00:00')
        .local()
        .format('dddd, DD MMM);
```

the out put:

```
Friday, 02 Sep
```

But I want the above result about our language in Vietnam as follows:

```
Thứ 7, 02 tháng 9
```

i tried as follows:

```
Moment('2022-09-02T02:00:00+00:00')
        .local()
        .format('dddd, DD MMM).locale('vi')
```

But it not slove this issue, so Does you guys help me this issue:
Thanks,

Comment: what is `7` here `Thứ 7, 02 tháng 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not same as you want but problem is you have to import `localization` also.

```
import moment from "moment";
import vi from "moment/locale/vi";
import fr from "moment/locale/fr";

const newVi = moment("2022-09-03T02:00:00+00:00").locale("vi", vi).format("dddd D, MMMM");
console.log(newVi);
const newFr = moment("2022-09-03T02:00:00+00:00").locale("vi", fr).format("dddd D, MMMM");  
console.log(newVi);
```

Comment: yep, thanks for your question, but if i switch to Japan language it keep Vietname locale, because this app using multiple language, , so does have another way

Comment: @Thang i have updated my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: once again thanks for so much. your answer helped me resolve this question.